# Eas-cli returns Error GraphQL request failed. What should i do?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm getting this error for all eas-cli commands.

Error: GraphQL request failed.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution to this? Or at least what the root cause is?

Comment: Yes! for some reason after reseting my internet router it worked

Comment: Getting the same error in 2024. Updating eas-cli didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help someone. The same thing happened to me. I waited about an hour and tried again and it worked. Perhaps it was a temporary service issue from EAS. I ran `npm install -g eas-cli` again just to make sure that was up-to-date as well.

Comment: tried again when i saw this and it worked